# Trying to detect i2c sensor on raspberry pi 2

Tags: sensors, i2c, raspberry-pi2

I followed all the [instructions](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruits-raspberry-pi-lesson-4-gpio-setup/configuring-i2c) but my Pi 2 doesn´t detect i2c:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~/Adafruit_Python_BMP/examples $ sudo i2cdetect -y 1             
Error: Could not open file `/dev/i2c-1' or `/dev/i2c/1': No such file or directory
```

I tried raspi-config and manually but insist with error.

Comment: using the code: `pi@raspberrypi ~/Adafruit_Python_BMP/examples $ sudo python simpletest.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "simpletest.py", line 37, in <module>
    sensor = BMP085.BMP085()
  File "build/bdist.linux-armv7l/egg/Adafruit_BMP/BMP085.py", line 66, in __init__
  File "build/bdist.linux-armv7l/egg/Adafruit_GPIO/I2C.py", line 66, in get_i2c_device
  File "build/bdist.linux-armv7l/egg/Adafruit_GPIO/I2C.py", line 95, in __init__
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory`

Comment: trying a different [code](https://bitbucket.org/MattHawkinsUK/rpispy-misc/raw/master/python/bmp180.py): `pi@raspberrypi ~ $ sudo python bosch.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bosch.py", line 8, in <module>
    bus = smbus.SMBus(1) # Rev 2 Pi uses 1
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
`